# Add RASTER layer with REST API

Tags: python, api, geoserver

Trying to add a raster layer to GeoServer using the rest API but I keep getting response 415 .which say unsupported media .please can someone help me out?below are my codes

```
coveragestore = 'gmes20241'
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/cite/datastores/" + coveragestore  + "/external.tif"
data = "/home/ernest/Desktop/BASIS/BaSIS_DATA/area_Councils/ar/ADANSI EAST/adansi east_ea.tif"
auth = ("admin", "geoserver")

response = requests.put(url, data=data, auth=auth)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content type header to `Content-type: image/tiff` so that GeoServer can tell what it is receiving.

Comment: added that and am getting this response now   "Could not aquire reader for coverage."